# getting error tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified when trying to connect from jenkins to jmeter servers

Tags: linux, jenkins, jmeter

i am using distributed framework for performance testing where i have 1 controller jmeter machine and 2 jmeter machines are working as load generators.I am trying to connect all the machines from jenkins server and executing shell script on controller machine to execute the test.Setup was working fine but from last couple of days i start getting following error

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

Below are the shell scripts, i am executing from jenkins server

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME=jmeter
HOSTS="jmeter01.com jmeter02.com"

#SCRIPT="source .bash_profile; alias ; pwd"

for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ; do
  echo "Connecting with host name : ${HOSTNAME}"
  ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${USERNAME}@${HOSTNAME}  "${SCRIPT}" 
  echo "ssh connection successful with ${HOSTNAME} "
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try 't' instead of 'T'

```
ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${USERNAME}@${HOSTNAME}  "${SCRIPT}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much.did not get any error by changing it to lowercase.